# adding a NOT-constraint in pyscipopt

Tags: python, optimization, scip

I'd like to add a NOT-constraint to my PySCIPOpt model. I can see `andConsAnd`, `addConsOr` and `addConsXor` but there isn't one for the NOT operator. What would be the easiest way to add a NOT-constraint?

I came up with:

```
x = model.addVar('B')
not_x = model.addVar('B')

model.addCons(not_x == (x - 1) * (x - 1))
```

but that seems ugly.

The reason I need `not_x` is because I'd like to add it later to a conjunction, like:

```
model.addConsAnd([not_x, y], True)
```

But, as far as I can see, PySCIPOpt interface does not work if I do it using Python not operator:

```py
model.addConsAdd([not x, y], True)
```

so the above line breaks the Kernel in my jupyter notebook.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `not x = 1 - x`

Comment: Of course! I thought it must be something super simple :-) Many thanks.
Please add it as the answer to get some points back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `not x` for a binary variable `x` is identical to `1-x`. This is used extensively in mixed-integer programming models.